# How to install tidy to xampp on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: php, xampp

I followed this article:
http://hoball.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/html-tidy-on-linux-under-xampp/

to install tidy on my xampp, and I got below error message when restart my xampp:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/tidy.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/tidy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64, how can I compile 32bit tidy? or is it possible to download tidy 32bit module from somewhere?

Thank you!

===================

I finally solved this problem by installing a 32bit ubuntu virtual box and do the compile in it.

Answer (score 0):

Under the blog, it says to do this:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config --with-tidy
```

Replace that line with:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config --with-tidy --host=i686-linux-gnu CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038073/999400

Comment: still not work, I got below errors:

*checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep*

Comment: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for i686-linux-gnu-cc... no
checking for i686-linux-gnu-gcc... no
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/php-5.3.8/ext/tidy':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: Could you post the contents of config.log to `http://paste.ubuntu.com/` and send the link here?